# org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "button"

Tags: selenium, exception

my html code of the selected element is:

I am not able to figure out why this error is there.

Comment: You're missing the html code

Comment: html code is:<button class="btn btn-default form-control ui-select-match btn-default-focus" ng-click="$select.activate()" ;="" ng-class="{'btn-default-focus':$select.focus}" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" ng-hide="$select.open" tabindex="-1" type="button" placeholder="Select or search a manufacturer in the list..." style="">

Answer (score 0):

Try below Xpath:-

```
//button[@class='btn btn-default form-control ui-select-match btn-default-focus']
```

OR

```
//button[@placeholder='Select or search a manufacturer in the list...']
```

OR more specific:-

```
//button[@placeholder='Select or search a manufacturer in the list...' and @class='btn btn-default form-control ui-select-match btn-default-focus']
```

If your problem is that the element is scrolled off the screen (and as a result under something like a header bar), you can try scrolling it back into view like this:

```
private void scrollToElementAndClick(WebElement element) { 
      int yScrollPosition = element.getLocation().getY(); 
       JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       js.executeScript("window.scroll(0, " + yScrollPosition + ");"); 
       element.click(); 
}
```

if you need you could also add in a static offset (if for example you have a page header that is 200px high and always displayed):

```
public static final int HEADER_OFFSET = 200; 
    private void scrollToElementAndClick(WebElement element) { 
    int yScrollPosition = element.getLocation().getY() - HEADER-OFFSET; 
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scroll(0, " + yScrollPosition + ");"); 
    element.click(); 
}
```

If nothing works then use `JavascriptExecutor` . It's an interface provided by Selenium but it's not a good practice to use it as it directly working on DOM

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By."Your Locator"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: 2nd one is locating to the HTML code block when pasted in xpath and clicked on Enter.But its not locating the element...1st and 3rd xpaths are not locating to HTML or element..

Comment: 2nd one click on enter but not locating the element .. means?

Comment: is after click nothing happens ?

Comment: when we paste the xpath on the firebug xpath location and if we clicks enter,firebug should find the desired element right?

Comment: after clicking enter,nothing happening.Just opening the HTML code again but not highlighting our element on browser..

Comment: I have tried to select the element by 1)xpath.click(), 2)xpath.sendkeys(keys.down),then xpath.sendkeys(keys.enter),               3)using Select osel=new Select(el1);
        osel.selectByVisibleText("Pilling");                                                 4)List<WebElement>olist=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='view']/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div/button"));
        olist.get(3).click();   but it is just locating the select box but not clicking an item from that list.

Comment: it is developed by AngularJS--name is UI select...pls help me out to select an item from that UI select list..